# Probability with a dice

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

A dice is thrown until number $6$ appeared. What is the probability that at least three throws were necessary, if $6$ didn't appeared in the first throw.

Comment: To say that it took at least three throws to get the first 6 is the same as to say that 6 didn't appear in the first two throws.

Comment: Quibble: 'mouse/mice' ... 'die/dice'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a 6 appearing on the second throw is 1/6 since there was no 6 on throw #1. So the probability is just 1-1/6=5/6.